# C++ lambda, member function call by value faster than by reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, lambda

Why is passing this by value faster than by reference in a lambda? By value compared to by reference is every time 1-2% faster.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    Foo(int value) { this->value = value;  }

    std::function<int()> lambdaTestByValue();
    std::function<int()> lambdaTestByReference();
};

std::function<int ()> Foo::lambdaTestByValue()
{
    return [=]() { return value; };
}

std::function<int()> Foo::lambdaTestByReference()
{
    return [&]() { return value; };
}
```

What makes by reference slower in this case? This applies with or without optimizations.

Comment: Oh no 1-2%! How did you benchmark it?

Comment: A difference of 1-2% might have many other reasons.

Comment: For example: http://pastebin.com/Va7u0ZMp

Comment: @Dagob which version of VS, Windows, etc.... as that all effects this

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2012 and Windows 8.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse. I'm not sure what you mean by 'tracking changes'. c++ does not work that way. If you pass something by ref all work is done directly on the original object, not on a copy on which changes are applied later on...

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan I thought it did, well you learn something new everyday

Comment: What are you testing?  How fast it returns with a lambda, or how fast the lambda runs?  Or both? - Edit: I just looked at your pastebin.  You're testing BOTH.  Isolate each first.

Comment: @Dagob unfortunately your setup is not [reliable for any sort of benchmarking](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/164209-windows-8-banned-by-worlds-top-benchmarking-and-overclocking-site).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have profiled correctly and this isn't a wild goose chase, take a look at the assembly difference of the generated code and see what's difference.

It could also be the small object optimization, i.e. if the state is small enough in std::function it will store the data in the object itself, if the function captured is larger it will be stored on the heap which would require an indirection and lookup.

Comment: Both methods will store exactly the same thing - `this`, a pointer.